# How to divide a cell value by entire row values in excel/libreoffice calc?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, libreoffice-calc

How to divide a cell value easily by entire row values in excel/libreoffice calc as like below:

[image]

In the image I did manually A2/B1, A2/C1, A2/D1, A2/E1, A2/F1, and same for A3,A4,A5,A6.

Now I need easy shortcut for huge values. Guide me with easy methods. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$` sign to block the Cell references so you can drag the formulas. In your case, place the following formula on cell `B2` and then copy it to the rest of the spreadsheet:

```
=$A2/B$1
```

You can find more info on the dollar sign on this [link](http://dedicatedexcel.com/dollar-signs-in-excel-formula/).